# Error in installing new rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been following the RoR tutorial and they suggested that if you have installed rails 4.1.1 then uninstall this and install rails 4.0.5. So I did following steps:

```
$ gem uninstall rails 
$ gem install rails --version 4.0.5
```

then it says

```
successfully installed rails-4.0.5
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-4.0.5
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-4.0.5
```

then,`c:\Sites>`

When I typed `$rails -v`
it says `Rails 4.1.1`

but i have installed  `Rails 4.0.5`

What should I do to install rails 4.0.5 and to remove 4.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall rails as:-

```
gem uninstall railties
```

Select the option of **railties-4.1.1** to uninstall it.

Install rails as

```
gem install rails --version 4.0.5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shamsul. Now I am having 4.0.5. :)

Comment: Sorry @Shamsul, I am new to stackoverflow so my reputation is low and I need 15 points to upvote and mine is only 6.